# PowerBI Text Box - anomalous black dots on published dashboard

Tags: textbox, powerbi

When publishing a dashboard from **PowerBI Desktop** to PowerBI's web interface, I've encountered spurious black dots appearing along the bottom of a text box.

I've tried moving the text box, checking other objects nearby, and changing its border settings, but the dots are definitely being produced by the text box itself, regardless of its attributes.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all text boxes and fonts display identically in Desktop and Online. Check that the word spacing in your text box has not increased when you published it - if additional spaces have appeared and pushed one or more words off the end of the text box, these may have appeared on a second line, and then been clipped by the text box size to only show the tops of the lettering.